# How to use external templates for ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs

I am learning ReactJS and in ALL examples that I see on the web the HTML code is always rendered inline, meaning that you have to add all HTML markup directly into the JS file which is super ugly and very hard to work with (if you have a lot of markup). Isn´t there a way to put all HTML in a separate file just referens that file when rendering? Like we do in Rails or Angular 2.

This is my code:

```
var Main = React.createClass({ 
    render() { 
        return ( 
            <div> <h1>Hello, World!</h1> </div> 
        ) 
    } 
});
```

I want to put this in a separate file:

```
<div> <h1>Hello, World!</h1> </div>
```

Comment: You need to create a child component for this

Comment: Mm, that is really a huge disadvantage compared to Angular 2 if I have to add all HTML directly to the JS file. It is like when we added styling directly inline to the HTML markup before CSS-files made an entrance...

Comment: Correct. In Angular We  can do this. But in React, everything need be inside jsx. No html file.

Comment: It's not HTML, it's JSX, which happens to look similar to HTML but it really just a fancy syntax for some functions.

Comment: Wow, that is really a huge downer. Back to Angular 2 then. Thanks!

Comment: Is this really a disadvantage.? You can still create a JSX with your HTML and resue it at anyplace.

Comment: How is this a disadvantage? Rather than tracking down 1) your JS file, 2) your HTML template and 3) your style sheet, everything is contained within 1 file in React, which is what W3C wants anyway with Web Components. I used to code ng1, and the environment you're describing is a step backwards IMHO.

Comment: Related (older) question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/34380973/438970

Answer (score -1):

You can put your html in a separate .js file and import it in your component then use,

**htmlMarkup.js**

```
module.exports = `<div> <h1>Hello, World!</h1> </div>`;
```

and then in your component

```
render() {
  return (<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={require('path/to/htmlMarkup.js')} />)
}
```

if you want to set some property in your html file, then you can export a function instead of string.

```
module.exports = (message) => `<div> <h1>${message}</h1> </div>`;
```

and then in render method.

```
render() {
  return (<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={require('path/to/htmlMarkup.js')('Hello World')} />)
}
```